# Center SVG of unknown origin into known SVG

Tags: svg, positioning

I have a program (Java-based) that generates SVG's from data. It is possible for a user to upload their own SVG's so they are used for icons and markers I use in the final SVG image.

How this works is that I have a placholder rectangle which I replace with the SVG supplied...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="176" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 264 176" width="264">
   <!-- my own stuff -->
   <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="placeholder" />
</svg>
```

Now I can replace the rect in my code with some other SVG and I add the width and height attributes so it scales.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="500">
   <!-- my own stuff -->
   <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- inner unknown XML -->
    </svg>
</svg>
```

The problem is that if the external SVG's are not square (1:1) you'll always get an offset in the horizontal or vertical direction. This could easily be remedied by reading out the values for the viewBox from the external SVG's. But those are not always present.

If I open the external SVG in Chrome I can see the *calculated* values of the width and height, but in my Java code I can not access the calculated width and height ofcourse.

The only solution I see is forcing the user to include a viewBox attribute. Are there any other solutions, like positioning an element based on its (calculated) centroid?

Answer (score 0):

The complete algorithm used by SVG renderers to establish intrinsic sizes is in the spec under [Intrinsic sizing properties of the viewport of SVG content](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#IntrinsicSizing), but for the purpose of inlining one svg inside another, it can be simplified:

- `x` and `y` attributes on the external SVG are to be ignored
- if the external SVG has a `viewBox` attribute, use it. Else,

  - if the external SVG is missing at least one of `width` or `height`, it is to be assumed `100%`
  - if `width` or `height` are in [absolute](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#absolute-lengths) or [font-relative](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#font-relative-lengths) units, resolve them to user units
  - if `width` or `height` are in percentage units, resolve them as percentages of the placeholder size to user units
- set a `viewBox` of `"0 0 <width> height>"` with the resolved values
- set `width` and `height` to the placeholder values
- set [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) to position the viewBox in the viewport